# Finding the Number of Elements in an Array of Command Line Arguments?

Tags: c++, arrays, shell, command-line, g++

I'm working off of a Linux command line with g++ and the code will be executed like so:

```
./mycode arg1 arg2 arg3 ...
```

This works fine as I am using the array `argv[]` and the following for main:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
```

However there is a part of my program where I need to know the **number** of command line arguments given. `sizeof()` is failing me here. Any ideas of how this could be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the `argc` parameter is meant for - it is the **ARG**ument **C**ount of the `argv` (**ARG**ument **V**alue) array.